# NS3 log Time precision

Tags: c++, python-2.7, gcc, ns-3

I am using NS3.20 to find the time stamps of packet being sent from a node to another node in a FAT-TREE topology using the command

```
NS_LOG= "*=level_info|prefix_func|prefix_time|prefix_node" ./waf --run scratch/fat-tree &> save-log.txt
```

After grepping few selected lines containing info about pkt 196.The output is of the form

Timestamp, Nodeid, Functioncalled, DevNo, pktid

Example lines are as follows

```
1.74547s 34 CsmaChannel:TransmitStart(): UID is 196)
1.74548s 34 CsmaChannel:TransmitEnd(): UID is 196)
1.74548s 23 Node:ReceiveFromDevice(): Node 23 ReceiveFromDevice:  dev 2 (type=ns3::CsmaNetDevice) Packet UID 196
1.74548s 23 BridgeNetDevice:ReceiveFromDevice(): UID is 196
1.74548s 23 CsmaChannel:TransmitStart(): UID is 196)
1.74548s 34 CsmaChannel:PropagationCompleteEvent(): UID is 196)
.
.
.
```

For my research I need the time stamps to be in nanoseconds. Is there a way to configure this?
NB : I tried cout, and fout within the functions but it just prints time without the node_id which is useless for me.

Please help

Comment: You can timestamp a packet based on this link https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/class_timestamp_tag.html

Answer (score 0):

First, I will suggest using the latest  version of ns-3, ns-3.30.1. Generally, it is a good idea to stay up-to-date. That being said my solution was tested using ns-3.30.1, so it is quite possible it doesn't work with ns-3.20. If it doesn't work, refer to the comments in [`sample-log-time-format.cc`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/sample-log-time-format_8cc.html).

I referenced §11.3 of the [ns-3 manual](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/ns-3-manual.pdf), which pointed me to the example, [`./src/core/examples/sample-log-time-format.cc`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/sample-log-time-format_8cc.html). Based off of that example, here is a minimal reproducible example of your desired output.

```
/* -*- Mode:C++; c-file-style:"gnu"; indent-tabs-mode:nil; -*- */
// set the time format and precision of LOG macros
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148908
// this example is adapted from ./src/core/examples/sample-log-time-format.cc

#include "ns3/simulator.h"
#include "ns3/log.h"
#include "ns3/random-variable-stream.h"

using namespace ns3;

void
ReplacementTimePrinter (std::ostream &os)
{
    os << Simulator::Now ().GetNanoSeconds () << " ns";
}

void
ReplaceTimePrinter (void)
{
    std::cout << "Replacing time printer function after Simulator::Run ()" << std::endl;
    LogSetTimePrinter (&ReplacementTimePrinter);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LogComponentEnable ("RandomVariableStream", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    LogComponentEnableAll (LOG_PREFIX_TIME);
    Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> uniformRv = CreateObject<UniformRandomVariable> ();
    Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (0), &ReplaceTimePrinter);

    // schedule some bogus events to demonstrate the new TimePrinter
    Simulator::Schedule (NanoSeconds (1), &UniformRandomVariable::SetAntithetic, uniformRv, false);
    Simulator::Schedule (NanoSeconds (123), &UniformRandomVariable::SetAntithetic, uniformRv, false);
    Simulator::Schedule (NanoSeconds (123456), &UniformRandomVariable::SetAntithetic, uniformRv, false);
    Simulator::Schedule (NanoSeconds (123456789), &UniformRandomVariable::SetAntithetic, uniformRv, false);

    Simulator::Run ();
    Simulator::Destroy ();
}
```

Use

```
./waf --run <program-name>
```

to run your program, and output should be

```
RandomVariableStream:RandomVariableStream(0x7fc0aee287d0)
RandomVariableStream:UniformRandomVariable(0x7fc0aee287d0)
RandomVariableStream:SetStream(0x7fc0aee287d0, -1)
RandomVariableStream:SetAntithetic(0x7fc0aee287d0, 0)
Replacing time printer function after Simulator::Run ()
1 ns RandomVariableStream:SetAntithetic(0x7fc0aee287d0, 0)
123 ns RandomVariableStream:SetAntithetic(0x7fc0aee287d0, 0)
123456 ns RandomVariableStream:SetAntithetic(0x7fc0aee287d0, 0)
123456789 ns RandomVariableStream:SetAntithetic(0x7fc0aee287d0, 0)
RandomVariableStream:~RandomVariableStream(0x7fc0aee287d0)
```

Notice that rather than directly calling `LogSetTimePrinter` in our simulator code, we schedule an Event that will call `LogSetTimePrinter` instead with

```
Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (0), &ReplaceTimePrinter);
```

I wasn't sure why this is the case, but on further inspection of [it's documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/namespacens3.html#a46cd76678f7da29799d1b41994e12ec1), it appears that `GetImpl()` calls `LogSetTimePrinter`. `GetImpl()` is called by `Simulator::Run()` which means that `Simulator::Run()` will "override" any calls to `LogSetTimePrinter` before `Simulator::Run()` is called. Thus, we need to create an Event that sets the `TimePrinter` after the `SimulatorImpl` has been created.